# Merge one array (list of objects) with same keys

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a rating system with php/mysql.

I have a simple rating object like this:
(t is type of rating, r is value of rating)

```
  [{"t":"1","r":2},{"t":"2","r":4},{"t":"3","r":1},{"t":"4","r":2},{"t":"5","r":2}]
```

In DB, I have a lot of rating records
Like this:

```
     object1=> [{"t":"1","r":2},{"t":"2","r":4},{"t":"3","r":1},{"t":"4","r":2},{"t":"5","r":2}]

     object2=> [{"t":"1","r":1},{"t":"2","r":5},{"t":"3","r":3},{"t":"4","r":3},{"t":"5","r":1}]
```

In short for output I need a new object like this (I need to calculate average rating, with same keys.)

```
objectAverageCalculated=> [{"t":"1","r":1.5},{"t":"2","r":4.5},{"t":"3","r":2},{"t":"4","r":2.5},{"t":"5","r":1.5}]
```

My sql:

```html
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` text NOT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `ratings` (`id`, `rating`, `item_id`) VALUES
(6, '[{\"t\":\"1\",\"r\":2},{\"t\":\"2\",\"r\":4},{\"t\":\"3\",\"r\":1},{\"t\":\"4\",\"r\":2},{\"t\":\"5\",\"r\":2}]', 'ABC123'),
(7, '[{\"t\":\"1\",\"r\":1},{\"t\":\"2\",\"r\":5},{\"t\":\"3\",\"r\":3},{\"t\":\"4\",\"r\":3},{\"t\":\"5\",\"r\":1}]', 'ABC123');


--
ALTER TABLE `ratings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);



ALTER TABLE `ratings`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;
```

My code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE item_id='ABC123' ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tempArray = json_decode($row['rating'], true);
    array_push($ratingsRaw, $tempArray);
}
```

I can not save every object with new variable (like $item1,$item2, etc...)

How can I store every object in one array and how can I get average of every rating type in one output object?

Comment: Please provide your data as tabular text. Databases don't have objects, they have rows and columns, so it is unclear what your actual table looks like.

Comment: @GMB You are right, I updated it now.

Comment: Your db seems messed up in your ratings-table. Why are you storing a JSON!?-string for the column rating? You should store only an integer (e.g. 7). Please read up on how to create a good database model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVG()` method in your MySQL query and retrieve average value directly from database.

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating FROM ratings WHERE item_id='ABC123'
```

Or when you don't specify `ID` and you want average value for all items.

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS avg_rating, item_id FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: Really great idea but the problem is we are saving ratings into a one object (text object) in mysql :(